# Faster Earth spinning speed to overcome gravity, possible?

Tags: gravity, rotation, speed

As far as I know we stick to the surface of the Earth as its gravity is pulling us and Earth rotation is in a way reducing the gravity.

At what speed should Earth be spinning so that we all get ejected / catapulted into space (if we all line up on the equator).

Sub question: at what speed of spinning would we all “stick” a few meters above the ground?

Comment: gajba, I would recommend asking this question on Physics.SE if you're still interested (assuming it hasn't already been answered there).

Comment: @called2voyage  I don't understand why it's off topic. A similar question has been asked before on Astronomy.SE. See [this](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/2313/if-earth-didnt-rotate-would-we-feel-heavier)

Comment: @Yashbhatt Thanks for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @Yashbhatt If you read the text in the close reason, it should become apparent to you why this question is off-topic.

Comment: @called2voyage It says "local/global phenomena might affect observations and measurements". The earth coming to a standstill or rotating fast enough to throw us off the surface is surely an observational phenomena.

Comment: @Yashbhatt The question isn't really framed about how it affects cosmic observation though. It is a poor use of the sight. Really, as I said, it is a better question for Physics.SE.

Comment: @called2voyage Well, the previous question also wasn't. But anyways, I see you flagged off that one too.

Comment: Short answer is no. See also: https://what-if.xkcd.com/92/